# What's the point of this OR with zero MIPS instruction?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm currently learning MIPS assembly for the r5900l processor, and I'm trying to read some code from a ps2 executable.

```
lui a0, 0x002B
...
addiu a0,a0,0xC0F0
or gp,a0,zero
```

Now, why do this or operation?
If I understand this correctly, the bitwise OR compares the binary value of a0 and zero, and if at least one of the two is 1, the value is 1, else it remains 0. But if zero is all 0, what's the point of doing the or operation? why not load the a0 register into gp?

(if you need more info I can post more code. Thanks in advance!)

Comment: *why not load the a0 register into gp?* That's exactly what it's doing, in one of the only ways the MIPS ISA provides for doing that.  If you mean why not LUI/ADDIU into `gp` in the first place, could be un-optimized code, or that it needed the value in both registers.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought that there was a command like, for example mov gp, a0 , but apparently mips doesnt have that

Comment: Yeah, only as a pseudo-instruction, `move gp, a0` as gusbro's answer points out.  You should probably accept that answer (with the checkmark under the vote arrows).

Answer (score 3):

The `OR` instruction applies a bitwise OR between each bit of the second and third argument (in your example between `a0` and `zero`) and stores the result in the first argument (`gp` in your example). As `zero` has all zeroes the net effect is that the contents of `a0` are copied to `gp`.

There is no `move` instruction in MIPS so you can perform that operation using other instructions, for example the one you provided.

Usually the assembler allows you to use pseudoinstructions which comprise one or more actual MIPS instructions (for example `la` is typically converted in `lui` + `ori`)
So a move `gp, a0` pseudoinstruction may be really assembled as a `or gp, a0, zero`.

Maybe you are looking at disassembled code and the disassembler didn't "reverse" the instructions into pseudoinstructions where applicable.

Comment: thank you for the explaination! Btw, yeah I'm looking at disassembled code from ps2dis, so that could be an explaination